# Monkey UI test on app with login

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I want to run the UI monkey test utility that comes with Android SDK on my app.

The problem is that the first screen you get in my app is a login screen, and if you are not successful in that screen then you are not allowed to see anything.

This way, my monkey tests always stay in the login screen, not being able to go past that.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while testing an app with espresso.
I solved it by creating an extra product flavor in my app.gradle like this:

```
    productFlavors {
        automated_test {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'CUSTOMFLAVOR', '"automated_test"'
        }
    }
```

Now you can check for example in your login activity if your are running this product flavor and skip the login process.

```
if(BuildConfig.CUSTOMFLAVOR.equals("automated_test")) {
        this.emailText.setText(getText(R.string.automated_test_username));
        this.passwordText.setText(getText(R.string.automated_test_password));
        login();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `monkey`, [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) *concertina mode* instead of sending pseudo-random events, analyzes the content of the screen and randomly selects a suitable event or action for the also randomly selected target, normally a View.

You can tweak it to send your desired username and password combinations instead of the default ones (e.g. `123456`, `querty`, etc.). See [concertina.py](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/concertina.py#L211).

Some details about *concertina mode* can also be found [here](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2015/08/culebra-concertina-mode.html).

Answer (score 0):

I made it with `adb shell`

```
adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/paid/release/app-paied-release.apk
adb shell am start -n my.app.package/my.app.package.LoginActivity
sleep 2
adb shell input text 'user@google.com'
adb shell input keyevent 61 
adb shell input text 'secret'
adb shell input keyevent 61 # to login button
adb shell input keyevent 66 # enter
```

now you can start monkey

```
adb shell monkey -p my.app.package -v 10000 -s 100
```

Comment: Meta: Stack Overflow doesn't support proper codeblocks with three backticks. Indent code blocks with four spaces instead.